# Puzzling php contact form not working. Any insights?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

This php contact form I'm using returns the message that my message has be sent but no email is received by the specified email address.

Here's the php:

```
<?php

$to = 'blahbahblah@gmail.com'; 

if($to) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$html = "";
$html .= "Name: " . htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "<br>\n";
$html .= "Email: " . htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "<br>\n";
$html .= "Message: " . htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "<br>\n";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";

$html = utf8_decode($html);

mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);

if ($html)
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'error';

} else {
echo "error";   
}
?>
```

And here's the html associated with it:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">

<p>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
</p>

<p> 
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
</p>

<div class="textarea-wrapper">
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>

<button id="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

I realize issues like these are frequent, but I've unable to figure it out. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem in that. define clearly your exact problem

Comment: To use the PHP mail() function, PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp

Comment: I fill the forms on the site, I click send, the 'your message has been sent. thank you.' message. However no mail is received by the email address I entered in the form.

Comment: Your first point is to look at what `mail` call returns. If it returns false, you are not able to even to deliver the mail (probably because you are not able to connect to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<br>\n"
```

use `"\r\n"` instead and try again

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your SMTP settings per your conversation with the support rep. These are set in your PHP.INI
The From address should belong to the domain from where you are running the script. If your script is running on your-website.com then the From address should be like xyz@website-name.com
**$headers = "From: xyz@website-name.com";
mail($to,$subj,$body,$headers);**

To check the contact form that I have used, visit: http://manageproac.com/support/